# looping .mpeg dump

Tags: video, bash, vlc-media-player, ffmpeg, mpeg

Need to dump an MPEG2 file in a loop, either to stdout or a named pipe.

This works:

```
$ { while : ; do cat myLoop.mpg; done; } | vlc -
```

This works on a text file containing "1234\n":

```
$ mkfifo myPipe
$ cat test.txt > myPipe & < myPipe tee -a myPipe | cat -
```

(it correctly loops, outputting "1234" on every line). Why does the following NOT work?

```
$ cat myLoop.mpg > myPipe & < myPipe tee -a myPipe | vlc myPipe
```

I'm primarily interested in re-writing the first statement to remove the improper "cat myLoop.mpg" statement. Will be inputting into VLC, or into FFMPEG and then piped into VLC.

Comment: Please review the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq). This is not a forum, please use comments to reply to others, edits to update your questions and answer only for... well answers.

Answer (score 1):

The last one probably doesn't work because you've got `vlc` reading from the named pipe instead of stdin.

See if this works:

```
cat myLoop.mpg > myPipe & < myPipe tee -a myPipe | vlc -
```

What's wrong with your first example? The curly braces aren't necessary, by the way:

```
while :; do cat myLoop.mpg; done | vlc -
```

Comment: Good catch. That was a typo in the post, not the problem, sadly. As you said, it should have been:

    cat myLoop.mpg > myPipe & < myPipe tee -a myPipe | vlc -

I was under the impression cat was for concatenating multiple files and using it to output a single file was inefficient/hackish. Reading/writting the same pipe + tee may not be any better. Question still stands if anyone has suggestions/alternatives.

Comment: @Matt: It's a useless use of `cat` when you use it to pass a file to another utility via a pipe when the utility will accept a filename as an argument `cat file | grep foo` vs. `grep foo file`. It's also unnecessary to use `cat` in Bash to read a file into a variable: `var=$(cat file)` vs. `var=$(<file)` or to feed it into a loop `cat file | while` vs. `while ... done < file`. However, sometimes `cat` is exactly right. I think my revision of your first example is one of those times. It's much more straightforward than the named pipe version.